# Selecting specific elements and finding their median using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, median

I have the following three data sets.

1. 2 3
2. 4 5
3. 6 6

---

1. 5 7
2. 7 4
3. 9 9

---

1. 1 8
2. 2 3
3. 3 2

Basically, i want to create a column where the elements will be the median of the corresponding elements of the second column. The first elements of the second column for each of the sets are (3,7,8) and median=7, second elements of the second column of the data sets are (5,4,3) and median=4 and third elements of the second column of data sets are (6,9,2) and median =6. So I want my output to be a numpy array like [(7,4,6)].

I tried the following approach:

```
import numpy as np
filelist=[]
for i in range (1,4):
    filelist.append("/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/A_%s.txt" %i)
for fname in filelist:
    data=np.loadtxt(fname)
    x=data[:,1]
    for j in range (0,3):
        y=np.median(x[j,1]) # tried this method and thought would get the arrays i want (3,7,8) , (5,4,3) and (6,9,2) and their medians
        print(y)
```

Received the following error : (IndexError: too many indices for array)

Any suggestion would mean a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice the second columns and use `np.median` along the appropriate axis -

```
np.median([a[:,1],b[:,1],c[:,1]],axis=0)
```

Or wrap as an array, then slice and finally use `np.median` -

```
np.median(np.asarray([a,b,c])[...,1], axis=0)
```

Or use `np.median`, that will take care of conversion to array under the hoods and then slice -

```
np.median([a,b,c],axis=0)[:,1]
```

So, if you have arrays as input, go with the first method for efficiency, otherwise the latter two would work just as well with arrays/lists.

Sample run -

```
In [10]: a = np.array([[2,3],[4,5],[5,6]])
    ...: b = np.array([[5,7],[7,4],[9,9]])
    ...: c = np.array([[1,8],[2,3],[3,2]])
    ...: 

In [11]: np.median([a[:,1],b[:,1],c[:,1]],axis=0)
Out[11]: array([ 7.,  4.,  6.])
```

---

To make it work with the posted code in the question :

```
# Grab filenames
filelist=[]
for i in range (1,4):
    filelist.append("/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/A_%s.txt" %i)

# Grab second columns off each
data_list = []
for fname in filelist:
    data=np.loadtxt(fname)
    data_list.append(data[:,1])

desired_output = np.median(data_list,axis=0)
```

Comment: Would you please suggest what should be the approach if I have to do the same thing but say for example 100 rows except only 3 like in this case. It would be difficult to define numpy arrays as a, b and c as you instructed.

Comment: @Hrihaan Three datasets each with 100 rows, you mean?

Comment: Yes, that would be so kind if you can instruct me for that approach so that I can do this for any situations@Divakar

Comment: @Hrihaan So, `filelist` holds the three input datasets, right? Then, just replace `[a,b,c]` with `filelist`. Should work. That is : `np.median(filelist,axis=0)[:,1]` or `np.median(np.asarray(filelist)[...,1], axis=0)`.

Comment: for fname in filelist:
    data=np.loadtxt(fname)
    x=np.median(filelist,axis=0)[:,1] 
    print(x) (I tried the above thing, got this error (TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type)

Comment: @Hrihaan What's in `filelist`?

Comment: print (filelist) so it prints the names of files (['/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/A_1.txt', '/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/A_2.txt', '/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/A_3.txt']

Comment: It works but one issue: My output is the last array, have no idea what are the first two arrays. [ 3.  5.  6.]
[ 5.   4.5  7.5]
[ 7.  4.  6.]

Comment: @Hrihaan What does `print(np.array(data_list).shape)` give you?

Comment: It gives: (1, 3)
(2, 3)
(3, 3)

Comment: @Hrihaan Well something is off. Anyway, it works for you, so we are all good I am guessing.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, it works but I just hope it gave me an array with the medians only so that I can work with it, but its also giving two other arrays which I don't know how to get rid off.

Comment: @Hrihaan `print(data_list)` after the loops and see what's in it. It should only have the second columns from each dataset. If not, as I said something is off. Good luck.

Comment: I did and as you said, it only has the second column values from each set.